# Javascript Array Object Errors on Multiple Values Push

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using a [Bootstrap DatePicker](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) so user can select the dates and at the back end, the selected dates will be stored in an array.

Whenever I select the dates, the javascript code `.push()` is used to capture the selected dates and append the selected dates in the array.

I believe this is the correct format for an array right?

```
DateSelected = ["April 1, 2021", "April 2, 2021", "April 3, 2021", "April 4, 2021"]
```

**BUT** what is happening is this:

```
DateSelected = ["April 1, 2021, April 2, 2021, April 3, 2021, April 4, 2021"]
```

So what happening here is its as if the array contains ONE (1) entry only whenever I `console.log(DateSelected.length)`. It should suppose to return FOUR (4) since I selected 4 dates.

Here's my code:

*Bootstrap Date Picker*

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    multidate: true,
    toggleActive: true
}).on('changeDate', function(e){
    $('#dt_due').val(
       $('.datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate') 
    );
});
```

*Javascript/ jQuery*

```
var DateInsured = [];
DateSelected.push($('#dt_due').val());

console.log(DateSelected)
console.log(DateSelected.length)
```

Here's a screenshot of the Google Chrome Console

[image]

Comment: `DateSelected = $('#dt_due').val().split(",")`

Comment: @adiga, can you post this as an answer. it technically solve my problem so I can reward you properly... Thank you very much!

Comment: That's okay. I've closed as a duplicate. The datepicker returns a single string of all the dates. You need to [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) that string at `,` character to get an array of each individual date strings.

Comment: oh i see. thank you very much @adiga! Have a great day!